# jquery toggle background color in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make an interactive menu with `jQuery` for practice. So far I have my dropdown menu, and a side table with a few elements in it.

[image]

So there are 4 elements in my dropdown menu aswell. My goal is the following: When the mouse is over the `first` element in my dropdown menu, the first cell from the table is turned red, just like in the image. When the mouse is over the second element from the dropdown list, the second cell (vertically) from the table turns red, and the first one returns to its original color.

So far I achieved to change the color of the first cell, when the mouse is over the first element from the dropdown menu. The problem is that it does not change back. I used:

```
$(".first-hover").hover(function(){
    $('#first').css({'backgroundColor':'red'})
});
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: you can easily apply these effect using css. Also share your HTML for better understanding.

Comment: You can solve it only with css. If you talk about menus I image that you are using lu > li > a structure. in css li:hover{background-color: red}. There is many tutorials of this in internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquerys `.hover()` method accepts two functions, the first for **mouseover** and the second for **mouseout**

```
$(".first-hover").hover(function(){
    // Mouse Over
    $('#first').css({'backgroundColor':'red'})
}, function(){
    // Mouse Out
    $('#first').removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this to change color back to original color.
Give a class to all your menu.

```
.redclass{
  background-color:red;
}

 .blueclass{
   background-color:blue;
  }

 $(".hover").hover(function(){

    if($(".hover").hasClass('redclass'))

  {
     $(".hover").removeClass('redclass')

     $(".hover").addClass('blueclass')
  }

   $(this).addClass('redclass')

});`
```